# Admob shows test ads but not real ads in beta version?

Tags: android, admob

i uploaded my app in beta version, my app is showing test interstitial ads instead of real ads but banner ads working fine. please anyone tell me is there any rule BETA show test ads instead of real ads whether banner is showing real.

Answer (score 0):

No, look for "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712" in your code, this is the id for a test ad. It must be there somewhere.
See https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads